# How to use Ajax with MVC, MySQL and Entity Framework, no razor pages

Tags: c#, html, mysql, .net

I messed up last time so let us see if I can get it right this time. I am trying to figure out first where to put the Ajax at and how to put it in my controller. First my controller looks like this
[update] I am trying to make my messages popup without refreshing. It works without ajax I just need someone to explain where to put in the ajax and how to interact with it. I don't want a alert I want the messages to update in that one section. In the answer I tried to figure out what he was saying yet this is what i got when I clicked send

`{"htmlMsg":"data addes to database successfull","htmlBody":"","success":true}`

I don't want to see this I want it to just update the message section. My goal has not been met yet so I am completely confused.

Underneath you see the image of it working before I added the ajax recommended. Now it sends me to that a different page.

[image: it working without ajax but how do I get that send button to add the messages]

```cs
[HttpGet("wall")]
        public IActionResult Wall(int userID)
        {
            ViewBag.User = GetUserInDB();
            // if(ViewBag.User == null)
            // {
            //     return RedirectToAction("Index");
            // }
            ViewBag.Messages = DBContext.Messages
                                .Include(i => i.Messenger)
                                .ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost("NewMessage/Add")]
        public IActionResult NewMessage( Message newMessage)
        {

            User userInDB = GetUserInDB();
            Message thisMessage = newMessage;
            System.Console.WriteLine(newMessage.TheMessage);
            thisMessage.UserID = userInDB.UserID;
           
            DBContext.Messages.Add(thisMessage);
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Wall");
        }
```

What I am trying to do is change the outline to it because I know I need to do something like this

```cs
[HttpPost("NewMessage/Add")]
        public JsonResult NewMessage( Message newMessage)
        {

            User userInDB = GetUserInDB();
            Message thisMessage = newMessage;
            thisMessage.UserID = userInDB.UserID;
           
            DBContext.Messages.Add(thisMessage);
            DBContext.SaveChanges();

            return Json(thisMessage);
        }
```

Is this correct? Or do I need to do something else?

Secondly I truly can't figure out the second part on the HTML section. Originally I had

```
@model Message

<div class="jumbotron p-2 m-3">
    <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="/images/melysLogo.jpg" alt="Logo Image"> </a>


    @if (ViewBag.User == null)
    {
        <a class="mr-2" href="/LoginOrRegister">Login Or Register</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a> <span>|</span>
        <a href="/AddRecipe"> Add Recipe</a><span>|</span>
        <a class="mr-2" href="/">Dashboard</a>
    }
     <span style="font-size:x-large;">Melly's Underground Cuisine</span>
</div>
<style>
    .messageboard {
        width: 97%;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<div class="messageboard m-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="m-3 p-3 sizeclass">
        @foreach (Message message in ViewBag.Messages)
        {   
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 p-3 ">
                <div class="p-2 rounded  largeLabel border">@message.TheMessage </div>
                    <div class="p-2 rounded smallLabel border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    @message.Messenger.FirstName
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="m-4">
    @if (ViewBag.User != null)
    {
        <form asp-action="NewMessage" asp-controller="Home"  a method="post">
            <input class="form-control-lg inputLabel m-1 " asp-for="TheMessage">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-warning m-2" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    }
</footer>
```

I have tried but don't understand what goes in the success section. I also don't know what class or should i make name or id up for the message itself in the data I tried this but am still lost

```js
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {  
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "/Home/NewMessage",  
                    data: { "name": $(".messageboard").val() },  //I am also guessing the class is probably wrong as well
                    success: function (response) {  
                          //what do I put here is what I am confused about as well
                    },  
                    failure: function (response) {  
                          console.log(response.failure)
                    },  
                    error: function (response) {  
                       console.log(response.error);  
                   }  
                });  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

I would love to also know if using vs code is not worth it for c# and .net core thank you so much sorry about my last question. I didn't follow the guidelines properly

Comment: my entire code before update is at my git hub
https://github.com/althepal78/melskitchen

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is my JSon request correct and What exactly do I do with the success call it is confusing to me. I am trying to make the page update a message when I create a new one not sure  how to do that

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the title about the question, not just a series of keywords. See [ask], the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Comment: I put the ajax script at the bottom of the footer you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Replace this code with your view code

```
@model Message

    <div class="jumbotron p-2 m-3">
        <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="/images/melysLogo.jpg" alt="Logo Image"> </a>


        @if (ViewBag.User == null)
        {
            <a class="mr-2" href="/LoginOrRegister">Login Or Register</a>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a> <span>|</span>
            <a href="/AddRecipe"> Add Recipe</a><span>|</span>
            <a class="mr-2" href="/">Dashboard</a>
        }
         <span style="font-size:x-large;">Melly's Underground Cuisine</span>
    </div>
    <style>
        .messageboard {
            width: 97%;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="messageboard m-3 p-3 rounded">
        <div class="m-3 p-3 sizeclass">
            @foreach (Message message in ViewBag.Messages)
            {   
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 p-3 ">
                    <div class="p-2 rounded  largeLabel border">@message.TheMessage </div>
                        <div class="p-2 rounded smallLabel border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        @message.Messenger.FirstName
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
     <footer id="myFooter" class="m-4">
            @if (ViewBag.User != null)
            {
                <form name="myForm" asp-action="NewMessage" asp-controller="Home"  a method="post">
                    <input class="form-control-lg inputLabel m-1 " asp-for="TheMessage">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-warning m-2" type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            }
        </footer>
  <script>
     $("#myform").submit( function () {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit    
            $.ajax({   
                type: "POST",
                data : $("#myForm").serialize(),
                cache: false,  
                url: "/Home/NewMessage",   
               success: function (result) {  
                    //what do I put here is what I am confused about as well
                    if(result.Succeess)
                    {
                        //do youy want work if success....
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //do youy want work if failed....
                    }
               },
               error: function (result) {  
                    console.log(result.error);    
            });   
            return false;   
    });
  </script>
```

2-Create a class in your project called JsonData

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string HtmlMsg { get; set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

and your NewMessage Action in controller change to:

```
[HttpPost("NewMessage/Add")]
public JsonResult NewMessage(Message newMessage)
{
  try
  {
     User userInDB = GetUserInDB();
     Message thisMessage = newMessage;
     thisMessage.UserID = userInDB.UserID;
           
     DBContext.Messages.Add(thisMessage);
     DBContext.SaveChanges();

     return Json(new JsonData()
     {
       HtmlMsg = "data add to database successfull",
       HtmlBody = "",
       Success = true,
     });
  }
  catch
  { 
      return Json(new JsonData()
     {
       HtmlMsg = "data add to database failed",
       HtmlBody = "",
       Success = false,
     });
  }

 
}
```

Comment: I am confused on the where to put the ajax call because you took it out, does it now go in the partial or stay on the same page? Secondly the url code in the ajax call doesn't seem to be correct, before you posted your answer I got a 404 in the console

Comment: also I don't understand the success portion. 
`success: function (response) {  
               
             $('#myfooter').html(response);
           },  ` like why do I want the response to be in the footer would I not want that to be in the messages  probably me overthinking stuff

Comment: Hey brother I tried that @html .partial but I got an error saying I had to use <partial name="thePartial">  I did that as well then it keeps giving me errors

Comment: I explained all the steps. Remove btnGet and use the script I provided instead .

Comment: And create a partialView for the footer and transfer the code I described to it. Use my code because I changed the element names

Comment: @meysamasid I understand you say you explained everything but you didn't explained it well enough for me to understand. you said to change my code to this for the ajax. where do I put that ajax for you took it out of the main wall.cshtml. Also I asked why you are using the the myfooter to put the response to when I want the message section to be changed. There are explanations but not really. Some people might have gotten what you said but do I change the ajax for the button or put what i had in a partial? that is a confusing part

Comment: I ask because one part you are saying change it then you are telling me to move the button so I am confused at that part

Comment: I modified the codes. Replace these codes with your own. The app works

Comment: Thanks a lot but once again where do I add the class jsondata. 2 Am I replacing the footer form with the ajax method you did because if so you should just delete the footer form and then add that in there. That is confusing

Comment: Also why am I alerting if it is successful I want it to add to the message. I am just confused at to what is going on to be honest. I am glad you changed and helped me but it is very confusing following your directions. I wish we could zoom so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: Create a folder in the project solution and name it Utility. Then add a class called JsonData. I entered the codes. You replace your codes exactly according to my codes.

Comment: Okay so I have done this and the result is that it goes to a different section just to show me the `{"htmlMsg":"data addes to database successfull","htmlBody":"","success":true}`

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do I am trying to make the ajax update the messages so when I click send the page does not reload. I just want the message to pop up on the section where the rest of the messages are and that is it.

Comment: I changed the code again. If you see the code correctly, it is quite understandable. When the Ajax request goes to the server and the execution result is returned

Comment: you have to show the appropriate message to the user based on the result sent from the server.

Comment: I prevented the page from reloading with e .preventdefault () and only the Ajax request is executed.

Comment: I want to say thank you before you think I am unappreciative, believe me I am not. What is happening with the code you have given to me I will show you what i mean about it. Underneath is a video I made for you to hopefully understand where I am trying to get to 
https://youtu.be/KEub5IdYkkQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227987/discussion-between-meysam-asadi-and-althepal78).

Comment: I was in the chat we can continue it there like you said.

Comment: Thanks a lot you got me half way there :)

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work thank you a lot but this is what I did

```cs
// wall html
@model Message

<div id="theDamMessages">
    <partial name="MessagePartial" />
</div>

<footer class="m-4">
    @if (ViewBag.User != null)
    {
        <form id="myform" method="POST">
            <input id="inputey" class="form-control-lg inputLabel m-1 " asp-for="TheMessage">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-warning m-2" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    }
</footer>
<div>
    <script>
        $("#myform").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url: "/AddMessage",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result)

                    $("#theDamMessages").html(result);

                    $("#myform")[0].reset();
                    var theheight = $(".messageboard")[0].scrollHeight;
                    $(".messageboard").scrollTop(theheight);
                },

                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }

            })
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

```cs
     [HttpPost("AddMessage")]
        public IActionResult AddMessage(Message newMessage)
        {

            User userInDB = GetUserInDB();
            Message thisMessage = newMessage;
            System.Console.WriteLine(newMessage.TheMessage);
            thisMessage.UserID = userInDB.UserID;

            DBContext.Messages.Add(thisMessage);
            DBContext.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Messages = DBContext.Messages
                                .Include(i => i.Messenger)
                                .ToList();          

            return PartialView("MessagePartial");
        }
```

```html
<div class="messageboard m-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="m-3 p-3 sizeclass">
        @foreach (Message message in ViewBag.Messages)
        {   
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around m-3 p-3 ">
                <div class="p-2 rounded  largeLabel border">@message.TheMessage </div>
            
                <div class="p-2 rounded smallLabel border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    @message.Messenger.FirstName
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guided as much as I could. Let's talk in chat.